# What does it mean to use the subjunctive after verbs of command?

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood

I'm looking at this quote:

> Thy dukedom I resign, and do entreat
>
> Thou pardon me my wrongs

I came around this site: http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.03.0080%3Asection%3D4%3Asubsection%3D12%3Aparagraph%3D369

It says that 'The Subjunctive after verbs of command and entreaty is especially common; naturally, since command implies a purpose'. But, in the quote, what is the 'subjunctive' and what is the 'verb of command'? Is this a common usage?

Comment: The verb *entreat* is what causes it to be the subjunctive (bare infinitive in form) *thou pardon* instead of the indicative *thou pardonest* with a finite verb inflection.

Answer (score 2):

It can be expanded in this way:

> Thy dukedom I resign, and [I] do entreat [Thee that] Thou *pardon* me my wrongs.

The mandative word eliciting the subjunctive is *entreat*. The verb in the subjunctive is *pardon*.

Is it common? Not today. [Entreat](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/entreat) means

> to ask (a person) earnestly; beseech; implore; beg

An example of the same kind of subjunctive today would be

> We *ask* that your child *stay* with you at all times.

where ask is the mandative word. The verb *stay* is easier to spot as the subjunctive because the third person singular is usually *stays*.

It's hard enough in modern times to spot the subjunctive. In archaic speech, it is much more so.

Comment: What medica has not spelled out is that, at the time, the indicative would have been "thou pardonest". "Thou pardon" is subjunctive (but in modern English, even early modern English, the present subjunctive is identical to the base form for every verb in the language).

Comment: @ColinFine - Thanks. I'm not familiar enough with English of that period (hence the last line: the hedge). If you want to expand the answer, please feel free. Otherwise this will wait till I have time to do some reading.